# I cannot change the background color of my python 2.7 tkinter application

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I have been working on a Python 2.7 Tkinter GUI application for some time. Recently, I have been trying to add a different background color to my application. However, I cannot seem to change it. Since the application has about 236 lines of code, you can find the code on GitHub [Here](https://github.com/austinprog/Find_Your_Youtuber/blob/master/main.py)
.

One of the solutions that I  tried was adding the standard Tkinter background module. At the line 225:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   app = ManagementofFrames()
   app.geometry('900x760')
   app.configure(background='black')
   app.title("FindYourYoutuber:V0.0.1-Alpha")
   app.mainloop()
```

However, the background still stays white.

For a visual, here is what it looks like. Even with the Tkinter background module added.
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqsrl.png)

Answer (score 1):

You should set the main frame's background:

```
class Home_Page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, background='black')
```

Hope it helps!